Could not execute the pipeline from the jupyuter notebook in kubeflow
I installed kubeflow using the single script as shown in the  manifests. But I have few problems.

First I don't see the configurations for this as shown in this issue



When I try to initialize the client I get this error and I don't see any instructions on how to set the KF_PIPELINES_SA_TOKEN_PATH variable as suggested here


